# Teste Unitário de Service Utilizando Karma (typescript/angular)

Tags: testes-de-unidade, angularjs-services, jasmine, angular

Estou tentando testar um método GET de uma service:

```
get(url: string, params?: any): Observable<Response> {
    let options = {};
    this.securityService.setHeaders(options);

    if (params)
        this.setParams(options, params.params);

    return this.http.get(url, options)
        .pipe(
            // retry(3), // retry a failed request up to 3 times
            map((res: Response) => {
                return res;
            }),
            catchError(this.handleError)
        );
}
```

O método `setHeaders` insere os headers da requisição e o access_token, consigo testa-lo até a parte do `map` mas não consigo testar a parte do retorno. Teria alguma solução de escrever um teste para percorrer o método inteiro?

Obs.: O método de `setParams` já está sendo garantido por outro teste.

Answer (score 0):

Eu faria algo assim:

```
  it('get should call correct api with correct payload', () => {
    let httpClient = TestBed.get(HttpClient);
    const obj = { response: 'superResponse' };
    const mockHttp = spyOn(httpClient, 'get').and.returnValue(of(obj));

    service.get('fakeUrl').subscribe(response => {
      expect(response).toEqual(obj);
    });

    const options={};

    expect(mockHttp).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
      'fakeUrl',
     options,
    );
  });
```

Comment: Tentei a solução e ele me retornou um erro, acredito que seja algo no spy: **Expected spy get to have been called with [ 'fakeUrl', Object({  }) ] but it was never called.**

Comment: Da uma olhada se vc esta usando o httpClient ou a versão mais antiga